# 3. I want to know how "be" is funtioning in this senstence

Tags: grammar

> In order for the process to be meaningful, it is proposed that the
>   engagement with schoolchildren **be** a continuous process in Kalaw.

Answer (score 1):

The second "be" in that sentence is in the [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood), which is mostly gone in English but shows up in some places. That's why it's not conjugated as "is."

Another example of the subjunctive is saying "If I were you..." rather than "If I was you..."

In the places where it's still used, it indicates a hypothetical or suggestion rather than a statement of fact. But I don't believe using the subjunctive would ever change the meaning of a sentence in English.

Answer (score 0):

> In order for the process to be meaningful, it is proposed that the engagement with schoolchildren would be a continuous process in Kalaw.

The first "be" implies that in order for the process to have any value or effect, you would have to do the latter action, which is in this case proposing engagement with schoolchildren.

The second "be" defines how aforementioned process proposal would be executed, in this case, continually.